# How to only show apps running in Windows?

Tags: python, window

I am trying to show *applications* running on Windows, but not the "tasklist". ex: chrome, zalo, ...

I opened "tasklist" => `os.system("tasklist")`. Please help me show only apps (chrome, zalo, ...

Comment: i 'm not sure of what you're asking. you want to emulate windows' task manager with python (and maybe tkinter)? you won't access the list of running processes through python `os`. first, you'll need to find how to do it using windows' command prompt. then you can execute that command with the module `subprocess`

Comment: i don't no. I want to show app running (name(zalo,chorme,...), PID) not all process in window.

Comment: for an operating system, process and app are basically the same thing. i think you should learn how to do what you want from the command-line and then try to make a gui with it